# WHERE statement not working in Joomla! 3.0.3. php request

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am trying to add a WHERE statement in a simple query in Joomla 3.0.3. but the code only works when I comment the line with the WHERE statement. Do you have any suggestion? Many thanks!

```
<?php

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select(array('Name','InstrumentFamily'));

$query->from('instrumenttype');

$query->where($db->nameQuote('InstrumentFamily').'='.$db->quote('debt'));

$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadAssocList();

print_r($result);

?>
```

PS: note that I'm using the Sourcerer extension to type such statements in the back end of Joomla!

Comment: Have you tried quoting them directly? ie. `$query->where('\`InstrumentFamily\`="debt"');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Joomla! 1.6.x `nameQuote` has been depreciated, in Joomla! 3.x it is no longer available. You can find more in this article "[Potential backward compatibility issues in Joomla 3.0 and Joomla Platform 12.1](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1)"

A lot of these `JDatabase` (aka `JDatabaseDriver`) changes are to enable greater support databases other than MySQL.

In Joomla! 3.x you will need to use the replacement `$db->quoteName()` for table or column names and `$db->quote` for any values.

So, your `where` element becomes:

```
$query->where($db->quoteName('InstrumentFamily').'='.$db->quote('debt'));
```

Comment: Thanks so much @cppl - this works great now! I'll be checking this article.