# Cannot modify an external database in Joomla! 3.0.3. using php request

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla-extensions

I have been creating a website on my local server with Joomla! 3.0.3.
I have successfully connected an external database to this website and can query it (see previous question of mine: [WHERE statement not working in Joomla! 3.0.3. php request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670555/where-statement-not-working-in-joomla-3-0-3-php-request)). But when I try to modify an entry in my external database, the server returns an error screen.

Here's the code I'm using in the back end of Joomla! (using the Sourcerer extension). I try to add a new currency to a MySQL "currency" table in my external database.

```
<?php

/**///////// LOAD EXTERNAL DATABASE (i.e. not the Joomla one) /////////**/

$option = array();
$option['driver'] = 'mysql'; // Database driver name
$option['host'] = 'localhost'; // Database host name
$option['user'] = 'root'; // User for database authentication
$option['password'] = ''; // Password for database authentication
$option['database'] = 'externaldatabase'; // Database name
$db = JDatabase::getInstance( $option );
/**///////// CREATE NEW QUERY OBJECT /////////**/

$query = $db->getQuery(true); //OK
/**///////// SELECT RECORDS & INSERT A NEW ROW /////////**/

$columns=array('ID', 'CurrencyCode', 'FullName');
$values=array('3', 'GBP', 'Pound Sterling');
$query->insert($db->quoteName('currency'));
$query->columns($db->quoteName($columns));
$query->values(implode(',', $values);

/**///////// RESET QUERY /////////**/

$db->setQuery($query); //OK

try {
    $result = $db->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // catch
}
?>
```

The browser returns the following two errors:

- **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\wamp\www\plugins\system\sourcerer\helper.php(450) : runtime-created function on line 46
- **Fatal error**: Function name must be a string in C:\wamp\www\plugins\system\sourcerer\helper.php on line 454

Do you have any suggestion? Thanks in advance for your help.

---

Here's the updated code that's working for those of you interested!

```
<?php
$values=array('3', '"GBP"', '"Pound Sterling"');
$query->insert($db->quoteName('currency'));
$query->columns($db->quoteName($columns));
$query->values(implode(',', $values)**)**;
?>
```

Comment: If `**///////// LOAD EXTERNAL DATABASE (i.e. not the Joomla one) /////////**` is present in your code then you want to use PHP comments properly

Comment: You're right - I just wanted to format the code comments in bold for the sake of readability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a closing parenthesis:

```
$query->values(implode(',', $values);
//                        Here ----^
```

So it must be:
`$query->values(implode(',', $values));`

Comment: Thanks a lot @HamZa DzCyberDeV it's a silly mistake. Now I don't have the errors anymore - the browser returns the typical html page. Still, the code is not working - I've been checking the currency table in phpMyAdmin and the only two entries I have in this in this table are **1 - EUR - Euro** and **2 - USD - US Dollar**. So no 3rd entry that would be **3 - GBP - Pound Sterling**. Any ideas what is going wrong with the code? PS: I've been trying to refresh in phpMyAdmin as well.

Comment: I have been the following at the end of my code `$err = $db->getErrorMsg(); echo $err;` and the browser returned the following **SQL=INSERT INTO `currency` (`ID`,`CurrencyCode`,`FullName`) VALUES (3,GBP,Pound Sterling)**. That's how I understood what **I was missing the quotation marks around the text strings**. Thank you all for your help! Cheers,

Comment: @FinanceGardener I was looking in the Joomla API for what was possibly going wrong, and now saw the "updated" code, +1 !!!